# Solving $AB+BA=XBX'$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Suppose $A$ is $d\times d$ positive definite matrix, I'd like to find a matrix $X$ such that the following is true for all positive definite matrices $d\times d$ matrices $B$

$$AB+BA=XBX^T$$

When does solution exist?
Is there a name for this equation?

Comment: This isn't exactly it, but it looks like the continuous Lyapunov equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation). For Dynamical Control Systems (namely nonlinear), we care about stability (will the values of the system stay finite, as opposed to some weird initial value causing some value(s) to approach infinity, to simplify), and finding a valid Lyapunov function for the system can prove stability. The Lyapunov equation is from applying this to $\dot{x} = Ax$

Comment: Is there any simple example where such $X$ exists for small $d$ (e.g. $d=2$)?

Comment: Sure, let A be identify matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, the equation is solvable if and only if $A$ is a positive scalar matrix.

Since $AB+BA=XBX^T$ for **all** positive definite matrices $B$, if we pass $B$ to a limit, the equation is still satisfied when $B$ is positive semidefinite. In particular, $Auu^T+uu^TA=(Xu)(Xu)^T$ for every nonzero vector $u$. Since the rank of the RHS is at most one, $Au$ must be a scalar multiple of $u$. As $u$ is arbitrary, this means every nonzero vector is an eigenvector of $A$ and hence $A$ is a scalar matrix. Thus $A=cI$ for some $c>0$ because $A$ is positive definite.

Conversely, if $A=cI$ for some $c>0$, we have $2cuu^T=(Xu)(Xu)^T$ for every nonzero vector $u$. Hence $Xu$ is identically equal to $\pm\sqrt{2c}u$, meaning that the only solutions are $X=\pm\sqrt{2c}I$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we prove the following properties:

**Property 1:**

If $\;M\;$ is a real symmetric matrix, there exists a symmetric matrix $\;M^{\frac{1}{2}}\;$ such that $\;M^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}=M.\;$ Moreover, if $\;M\;$ is positive definite, then $\;M^{\frac{1}{2}}\;$ is real.

**Proof:**

By applying the spectral theorem for real symmetric matrices, we get that there exists an orthogonal matrix $\;U\;$ such that $\;U^T\cdot M\cdot U=F\;$ is diagonal, hence

$M=U\cdot F\cdot U^T\;$.

Let $\;G\;$ be the diagonal matrix whose entries are the square roots of the entries of $\;F\;,\;$ so it results that $\;F=G\cdot G\;.$

The matrix $\;M^{\frac{1}{2}}=U\cdot G\cdot U^T\;$ is symmetric and

$\;M^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}=U\cdot G\cdot U^T\cdot U\cdot G\cdot U^T=U\cdot G\cdot G\cdot U^T=\\\qquad\qquad\;\;=U\cdot F\cdot U^T=M\;.$

Moreover, if $\;M\;$ is positive definite, then all its eigenvalues are positive, therefore all the diagonal entries of the matrix $\;F\;$ are positive too, consequently $\;G\;$ and $\;M^{\frac{1}{2}}\;$ are real matrices.

---

**Property 2:**

If $\;M\;$ is an invertible real symmetric matrix, then

$Y^T\cdot Y=M\implies\exists\;U$ orthogonal matrix such that $\;Y=U\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}\;.$

**Proof:**

By applying the Property 1, it follows that there exists a symmetric matrix $\;M^{\frac{1}{2}}\;$ such that $\;M^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}=M\;.$

Since $\;M\;$ is invertible, then $\;\det M\ne0\;,\;$ hence $\;\det\left(M^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\ne0\;,\;$ consequently $\;M^{\frac{1}{2}}\;$ is invertible too.

Given that $M^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is symmetric, then $\left(M^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{-1}$ is symmetric too.

If $\;Y^T\cdot Y=M\;,\;$ then

$Y^T\cdot Y=M^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}\;,$

$\left(M^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{-1}\cdot Y^T\cdot Y\cdot\left(M^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{-1}=I\;,$

$\left[Y\cdot\left(M^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{-1}\right]^T\cdot\left[Y\cdot\left(M^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{-1}\right]=I\;,\;$ hence

$Y\cdot\left(M^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{-1}=U\;$ is an othogonal matrix and

$Y=U\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}\;.$

---

**Property 3:**

If $\;M\;$ is a real symmetric matrix, then

$Y=U\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}\;$ where $\;U\;$ is any orthogonal matrix $\implies Y^T\cdot Y=M\;.$

**Proof:**

$Y^T\cdot Y=\left(U\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^T\cdot\left(U\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)=M^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot U^T\cdot U\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}=\\\qquad\quad=M^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot M^{\frac{1}{2}}=M\;.$

---

Now we are going to solve the matrix equation:

$X\cdot B\cdot X^T=AB+BA\;,\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

where $\;A\;$ and $\;B\;$ are positive definite matrices.

By applying the spectral theorem for real symmetric matrices, we get that there exists an orthogonal matrix $\;P\;$ such that $\;P^T\cdot B\cdot P=D\;$ is diagonal, hence

$B=P\cdot D\cdot P^T\;$.

Let $\;E\;$ be the diagonal matrix whose entries are the square roots of the entries of $\;D\;,\;$ so it results that $\;D=E\cdot E\;.$

Given that $\;B\;$ is a positive definite matrix, all its eigenvalues are positive, hence all the diagonal entries of $\;D\;$ and $\;E\;$ are positive too, consequently $\;D\;$ and $\;E\;$ are invertible matrices.

$X\cdot B\cdot X^T=AB+BA\;,$

$X\cdot P\cdot E\cdot E\cdot P^T\cdot X^T=AB+BA\;,$

$\left(E\cdot P^T\cdot X^T\right)^T\cdot E\cdot P^T\cdot X^T=AB+BA\;.$

By letting $\;Y=E\cdot P^T\cdot X^T\;,\;$ we get that

$Y^T\cdot Y=AB+BA\;.\quad\color{blue}{(**)}$

Since $\;AB+BA\;$ is a real symmetric matrix, by applying the Property 3, it follows that

$Y=Q\cdot\left(AB+BA\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

is a solution of the matrix equation $(**)$ whatever orthogonal matrix $\;Q\;$ is.

$Y=Q\cdot\left(AB+BA\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\;,\;$

$E\cdot P^T\cdot X^T=Q\cdot\left(AB+BA\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\;,\;$

$X^T=P\cdot E^{-1}\cdot Q\cdot\left(AB+BA\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\;,\;$

$X=\left(AB+BA\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot Q^T\cdot E^{-1}\cdot P^T\;.$

Therefore,

$X=\left(AB+BA\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot Q^T\cdot E^{-1}\cdot P^T\;,$

where $\;E,\;P\;$ are matrices such that $\;B=P\cdot E\cdot E\cdot P^T\;,$

is a solution of the matrix equation $(*)$ whatever orthogonal matrix $\;Q\;$ is.